# Page where I can see my user's managed files

Tags: 7, files

Is there a page in Drupal that lists all of the files in file_managed that the logged in user owns?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a pre-made page for this, but you can make one using Views.  Create a new view of type Files.  Under the Advanced section, add a Relationship for the user who uploaded the file.  Then add a filter "User: current" using this relationship.

[image: screenshot of Views admin UI]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a pre-made page. :)